# Global exception handler in CLR Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, clrstoredprocedure

I use C# and Sql Server 2008 and I have some try/catch blocks in my CLR Stored Procedure and these are caught. These are logged in a file and they return a code error and message using SqlPipe. These work fines.
Now I need to do the same when I have some untrapped errors especially to have a trace in the log file!

I tried to use Application.ThreadException but this class is not available in the CLR Stored Procedure (WinForms). Do I have to use a naughty try/catch block in my entry Sql Procedure method or is there something better to do?

Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server does not allow you to specify your own handler for *unhandled* exceptions. If an exception is not handled, SQL Server sends an error message to the user.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, SQL Server will dump unhandled exceptions to its own log file, in addition to returning them to the user. You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest approach will be to use a try..catch block in the CLR method being invoked.  Even better would be to keep the main functionality in a separate method that gets invoked by the CLR entry method:

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static void GetSomething(string value)
{
    try {
        DoGetSomething(value):
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // error handling
    }
}

private static void DoGetSomething(string value)
{
    // implementation goes here
}
```