# SQL Server equivalent of DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute following mySql statement

```
"DECLARE DONE INT(1) default 0;    
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET DONE = 1;"
```

in SQL Server 2005 like

```
" DECLARE @DONE INT,    
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET DONE = 1"
```

it gives error like

```
"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONTINUE'.
Msg 136, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Cannot use a CONTINUE statement outside the scope of a WHILE statement."
```

[MySQL DECLARE ... HANDLER command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html)

Comment: Check here: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-136.aspx - it should cover your question

Comment: You can't just type MySQL commands into SQL Server and expect them to work. It would help if you explain what `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER` actually does (or link to the docs), for the benefit of SQL Server people who may not be familiar with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has no direct equivalent of the handler mechanism described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html) linked above. The most obvious alternatives are:

- [`TRY...CATCH...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)
- Write a [CLR stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) and use .NET code to implement whatever handling code you need; [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956027/global-exception-handler-in-clr-stored-procedure) also has some useful information